# SKAction animateWithTextures not working properly

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I have been writing a game with a helicopter for a while and now I am trying to offer the user the option between two helis. I used this code to animate the original one, with no problems whatsoever:

```
heliAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"APACHE"];
NSArray *heliAtlasArray = [heliAtlas textureNames];
    NSArray *heliAtlasArraySorted = [heliAtlasArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSMutableArray *heliTextures = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *filename in heliAtlasArraySorted) {
        SKTexture *texture = [heliAtlas textureNamed:filename];
        [heliTextures addObject:texture];
    }
    SKAction *animateHeli = [SKAction animateWithTextures:heliTextures timePerFrame:.016];
    SKAction *repeatAnimation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animateHeli];
```

Now, I have used the exact same code for the second heli,but when I tried to use the heli, the animation looked glitched. I slowed down the animation, and I realized that it shows the first half of the animation, and then animates through the atlas style photos (with two side-by side helis cut in half or upside down, etc).

Why are my two atlases acting differently?

Comment: do the individual images have unique names? what's in the sorted array (log it)? The sorting probably does not consider natural sorting, so the order may be "image1, image10, image2" if you named them consecutively.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I did what you asked. For the heli that works, the NSLog showed me that the array contained the images in order. For the one that doesn't it contains the first few images properly and the next ones look like littlebird_frame07@2x         0x1851a8bbdng'

Comment: the names are correct up to and including frame 05. frames 06, 07 AND 08 are duplicates of frames 04, 03, and 02. maybe that's why, but then I don't know what to do. this is the same case with my other heli, but it hasn't had this glitch.

Comment: Also, I tried fixing it by manually putting in the image names, but for frames 06, 07 and 08 it shows the red x, even though I can clearly see in my project that they are in the atlas folder. Very frustrating, clearly apple is trying to "help me out" by making the atlas smaller but it's literally destroying images in the process

Comment: I noticed the same issue in my app. I ended up removing the images from the atlas.

Comment: @NGAFD This seems similar to my question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657442/textures-used-for-animatewithtextures-getting-lost-some-frames-show-red-x)  I use 45 textures for an animation however, less than the 50 you specified in your answer, but I don't create any atlases myself.  How can I tell if Xcode is adding other unrelated images to the atlases it creates.?  Perhaps it's doing that and bumping some of the images I need?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that an atlas has an image limit of 50. I've removed images until there were 50 left and it worked just fine from there.